# How to decode yahoo mail utf content get with pop3

Tags: email, yahoo, decode, pop3

I get email content with pop3 , but for utf (persian) content encoded!

how to decode?

```
<div style=3D"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:ti= mes new roman, new york, times, serif;font-size:12pt"><div>=D8=A8=D8=A7 =D8= =B3=D9=84=D8=A7=D9=85<br>=0A=D8=AF=D8=A7=D9=85=D9=86=D9=87 =D9=88=D8=A8=D8= =B3=D8=A7=DB=8C=D8=AA =D9=85=D9=86 aspek.ir =D9=87=D8=B3=D8=AA=D8=B4 =D9=88= aspek.info =D8=B1=D9=88 =D8=B1=D9=88=D8=B4 =D9=BE=D8=A7=D8=B1=DA=A9 =DA= =A9=D8=B1=D8=AF=D9=85<br>=0A=D8=A7=D9=85=D8=A7 =D8=A7=D9=85=D8=B1=D9=88=D8= =B2 =D8=AF=DB=8C=D8=AF=D9=85 =DB=8C=DA=A9 =D8=B4=D8=B1=DA=A9=D8=AA=DB=8C = =D8=B2=DB=8C=D8=B1 =D8=B4=D8=A7=D8=AE=D9=87 =D9=87=D8=A7=DB=8C =D9=88=D8=A8= =D8=B3=D8=A7=DB=8C=D8=AA =D9=85=D9=86 =D8=B1=D9=88 =D9=85=D8=AB=D9=84=D8=A7= =D9=8B =D8=A8=D8=B5=D9=88=D8=B1=D8=AA:<br>=0A<br>=0Aaspek.info/contact.html= <br>=0A=D8=AB=D8=A8=D8=AA =DA=A9=D8=B1=D8=AF=D9=87<br>=0A=D9=85=DB=8C=D8=AE= =D9=88=D8=A7=D8=B3=D8=AA=D9=85 =D8=A8=D8=A8=DB=8C=D9=86=D9=85 =DA=86=D8=B7= =D9=88=D8=B1=DB=8C =DA=86=D9=86=DB=8C=D9=86 =DA=86=DB=8C=D8=B2=DB=8C =D9=85= =D9=85=DA=A9=D9=86=D9=87=D8=9F<br>=0A=D8=A8=D8=A7 =D8=AA=D8=B4=DA=A9=D8=B1= =0A=09=09=09=09=09=0A=09=09=09=09=09</div></div>
```